# Difficulty in sprite texture alignment

Tags: three.js

I have some code similar to the following...

```
this.texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'spritesheet.png' );
this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: this.texture, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(32, 32, 1, 1);
this.sprite = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
game.scene.add( this.sprite );
```

I've also tried along the lines of...

```
    this.material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { 
    map: image, 
    useScreenCoordinates: true, 
    alignment: THREE.SpriteAlignment.center 
} );
    this.sprite = new THREE.Sprite( this.material );
```

These display the full spritesheet (sort of), as I would expect without further settings.

How do I align the sprite so it only displays say 32x32px starting at offset 50,60 for example ? The three.js documentation doesn't seem have much information, and the examples I've seen tend to use one image per sprite (which may be preferable, or only way possible ?)

Edit: I've spotted a material uvOffset and uvScale that I suspect is related to alignment in a Sprite object if anyone knows how these work. Will dig further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a "uvOffset" and "uvScale" parameter in spriteMaterial , i think you could use those but I cannot present any source code to you.

What you can of course do is using PlaneGeometry and calculate UV Coordinates for the 2 triangles (the plane). For example top-left is your offset and bottom right is calculated from a given offset and size (32x32) but using the whole image size in pixels to get the UV coordinates between 0 and 1

for example topleft is (50/imageSize, 60/imagesize) and bottom right is ( (50+32)/imgSize, (60+32)/imgSize). I think this should work, although i am not quite sure if you would get the result you want as OpenGL treats images "up side down". But you can try and go on from here. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just confirming, this has led me to a solution. I've now basically got spriteMaterial = new Three.spriteMaterial({ map : myTexture }) and then using uvOffset.x uvOffset.y uvScale.x, uvScale.y on those to adjust it. I've not needed to use PlaneGeometry, but I will check that again if I get stuck